# I cannot find permit button for access permission when running GAS

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I pressed `Run` button on the Google Apps Script page, I got the message below:

```
Authorization required
This project requires your permission to access your data.
```

I clicked `Review permissions` and moved on, and I landed to the permission page. However, I cannot find the permit/allow button. Where is it gone?
[image]

Comment: zoom out and you will find it. It is located at the bottom right side.

Comment: I found it. It was just that the button somehow turned invisible. Maybe  it was a influence of Chrome extensions `Dark Theme` and `Dark Reader` that I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved on my own. It was just that the button somehow turned invisible. I could find it and pushed it. Maybe it was a influence of Chrome extensions Dark Theme and Dark Reader that I'm using. Thanks.